# Two equations for position $x$ but gives different results?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

It seems that there are two equations for finding $x$:
$$
\begin{align*}
x & =x_0+vt\tag{1} \\
x & =x_0+vt+\frac{1}{2}at^2\tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$

But one can clearly see that the two equations will not give the same answers....

How can I decide which equation to even choose. I have an exam on kinematics but it's all so confusing for me....

Comment: What are the pre-conditions for the two equations (that is what are they equations *for*)? Is there any reason to expect them to give you the same results at all? Aside: this may well be the single most common question that students have in introductory kinematics, and I promise the answer was given to you in the material presented, you just didn't recognize it as important at the time. Look again.

Comment: While it makes sense to be more reluctant to solve homework problems, this appears to be someone making a genuine attempt to understand the material.

Comment: If you set $a$ = 0 in the second equation, you'll get the first equation. Thus you can consider the first equation as a special case of the second equation when the acceleration $a$ becomes 0.

Comment: No, there are not two equations for x. Kunal Pawar is correct.  Don't assume that because the equations look different that they are independent of each other. Understand the *concept* and *context* of equations.

Answer (score 3):

***tl;dr**-*  The equation with $a$ is the "real" equation.  The other equation is a simplified version that you can use ***if*** there's no acceleration.  The "real" equation always works and you can always use it.

#### Compare the equations

So you've got two equations:
$$
\begin{align*}
x & =x_0+vt\tag{1} \\
x & =x_0+vt+\frac{1}{2}at^2\tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$
where

- $x$ is position;
- $x_0$ is the initial position;

  - Note that $x=x_0$ when $t=0$; after that, $x$ can change, but $x_0$ stays the same.
- $t$ is time;
- $v$ is velocity;
- $a$ is acceleration.

What happens to Equation (2) if there's no acceleration?
$$
\begin{align*}
x & =x_0+vt+\frac{1}{2}at^2\tag{2} \\
& =x_0+vt+\frac{1}{2}\left(0\right)t^2 \\
& =x_0+vt+0 \\
& =x_0+vt \tag{1}
\end{align*}
$$
Seems like both equations are the same when $a=0$, right?  That's because Equation (2) is the more general form.  Equation (1)'s the simplified version that you can use when there's no acceleration.

#### Why two equations for the same thing?

Your class probably taught you Equation (1) because it's easier to understand.  But, Equation (2)'s the one that you really need to remember, since it works even when there's acceleration.

If you remember Equation (2) and know to assert $a=0$ whenever there's no acceleration, you can forget Equation (1).

#### Summary

Equation (1), $x=x_0+vt$:

- Easier for new students to remember.
- Works when there's no acceleration.
- Gives you the wrong answer if there is acceleration.

Equation (2), $x=x_0+vt+\frac{1}{2}at^2$:

- Harder to remember since it's bigger.
- Always works.
- Remember that if an exam question says that something is moving "with constant velocity" or has "no acceleration", then that means $a=0$.

Comment: You shouldn't say equation (2) always works; just like equation (1), it only works if all higher derivatives are equal to zero. The actual "real" equation is $x(t) = \sum t^n x^{(n)}(0)/n!$.

Comment: It also doesn't work as $t{\rightarrow}{\infty}$ due to relativity, or when $x\left(t\right)$ isn't expressible as a continuous derivative.  We don't have to be _[jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics))_-y about it.  ;-)  In all seriousness though, if anyone's trying to figure out @knzhou's comment, he's expressing $x$ via a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), where the gist is that $x$ is equal to an infinite sum of its derivatives time-displaced about an  initial position.  This topic's covered in taught in Calculus I.

Comment: So, to synthesize the answer and make it rigorous in a way that the OP understands it: the first equation is a special case of the second, and the second is a special case of the general answer of arbitrary acceleration as a function of time (not considered in high school, which only considers up to a constant acceleration).